# Postfix's received emails put in /var/mail/user/.Sent Messages

Tags: linux, postfix, dovecot, amazon-linux

For some reason, emails that I receive on my Amazon Linux EC2 instance, running postfix and dovecot, are put in the directory `/var/mail/<user>/.Sent\ Messages`, instead of the expected `/var/mail/<user>`.

Postfix's `master.cf` contains the following pertaining to dovecot

```
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
    flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/libexec/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}
```

and the `mail_location` in Dovecot's `dovecot.conf` is set to

```
maildir:/var/mail/%u
```

And here's the log for postfix and dovecot (`/var/log/maillog`)

> Sep  4 02:43:02 mail dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=, method=PLAIN, rip=108.23.86.62, lip=172.31.50.106, mpid=9156, TLS
>
> Sep  4 02:43:02 mail dovecot: imap(support): Disconnected: Logged out bytes=32/392
>   Sep  4 02:43:23 mail dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=, method=PLAIN, rip=108.23.86.62, lip=172.31.50.106, mpid=9158, TLS
>
> Sep  4 02:43:24 mail dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=, method=PLAIN, rip=108.23.86.62, lip=172.31.50.106, mpid=9160, TLS
>
> Sep  4 02:43:25 mail dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=, method=PLAIN, rip=108.23.86.62, lip=172.31.50.106, mpid=9162, TLS
>
> Sep  4 02:43:25 mail dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=, method=PLAIN, rip=108.23.86.62, lip=172.31.50.106, mpid=9164, TLS

All of the messages are received correctly, but they are just put in the incorrect directory, making dovecot not work properly.

Could this have something to do with the way I configured postfix?

Comment: Show logs from postfix and dovecot when it receiving message

Comment: @masegaloeh I can't believe I didn't include that, sorry! I just edited it in

Comment: Umm, the logs above doesn't include event when email received by your mail server. Try to send email to your server again and watch the logs when postfix receiving message.

Comment: @masegaloeh I'm not sure what happened, but I broke something with postfix, and it took me a few hours to fix it, but now that it's fixed, the problem no longer occurs... I have a feeling it had something to do with dovecot, though. I also set `home_mailbox` to `Maildir/` in postfix's `main.cf`, which was commented out before.

Comment: Feel free to add the solution in answer section below...

Comment: @masegaloeh I was about to, but it isn't actually an answer to the question - I'm going to add it if theres no other answers within a few hours

Comment: So, there are no answer?

Comment: @masegaloeh No - at least no direct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-installed both postfix and dovecot, and also set `home_mailbox` to `Maildir/` in postfix's `main.cf`.

Although I'm unsure, I assume the problem had something to do with the misconfiguration of either dovecot or postfix